# The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [rtoapp] lib\seriveSelection.dart:45)

Tags: flutter

**Hello Fluttermates,**

I am trying to use mediaquery to get screen size  and stoore it in a variable called size.
**I am doing this in another screen**
This is giving me this error

> The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [appname] lib\seriveSelection.dart:45)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Home',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "Antipasto"
          ),
        ),
      ),


      body: myapp(),
    );

  }
}

class myapp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _myappState createState() => _myappState();
}

class _myappState extends State<myapp> {
  var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              child: Card(
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome'
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mediaquery gets executed as soon as the state is instantiated, which is too early to access the context, that is not ready yet.
move it inside of the `build()` method.

```
class _myappState extends State<myapp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I figured it out yesterday.

Comment: @NOOB, sure, can you validate the answer ?

Comment: Thanks , sorry I am new to asking questions but done